# rsync - exclude only one file or directory with similar name to others

Tags: rsync

I'm using `rsync` to transfer a directory to another location:
`rsync -av ./ /var/www/html/some_project --exclude-from=ignore_these.txt`

In the current directory, I have a subdirectory named `testing` and a file named `config.json`

Deeper within the current directory, I have another subdirectory named `testing` and another file named `config.json`

I want the `rsync` transfer to exclude `./testing` and `./config.json` but *include* every other occurrence that may exist.

I'm using an exclusion file:

```
- ignore_these.txt
- testing
- config.json
```

Using this exclusion file, **all** `testing` and `config.json` items are excluded. If I prefix each with `./` then **none** are excluded bc. nothing ever matches `./testing` etc. I cannot explicitly "include" the sub-`config.json` nor sub-`testing` as this will not be maintainable as the project grows.

How do I exclude only the files/directories located within the CWD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should exclude the first level `{prova1,prova3}` files in the first level directory and then include the same files in the deeper levels:

```shell
rsync -av --include={\*/prova1,\*/prova3} --exclude={"prova1","prova3"} aa/ bb/
```